# HTTP Protocol Working

Tags: http

I need to ask a question about HTTP protocol. I am trying to develop a sandbox (web browser) where any one can surf the website with different identities. Different identity means that on each request to a page will be from different IP address.

Now I don't know how scripts on web servers check the IP address of the one who generated the request. This is possible and I am aware of this. But I need to know whether this is HTTP request header that has the IP address or something else.

Simply speaking, I want to fool the websites. :)

Umair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, the IP address is provided *EVERY* time you connect to *ANYTHING*. It has nothing to do with http headers.

See [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv4) -> packet structure -> header

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on the layers that build up a network from the wires[1] to the application.  I think you'll find the the IP address is known long before HTTP gets involved.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

[1] or photons, or radio waves, or smoke signals...

Comment: But is there any way I can generate IP address randomly and make requests then?

Comment: I don't see why not.  You mean on the client machine, change your IP and make a request?  I'm sure you can do that with a simple script.